# A first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is a problem I did. However, it did not match the back of the book. I would like to know where I went wrong.

Problem:

Solve the following differential equation.
$$ y' = \frac{y-x}{x} $$

Answer:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \dfrac{y}{x} - \dfrac{x}{x} =  \dfrac{y}{x} - 1 \\
y &= xv \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= x \dfrac{dv}{dx} + v \\
x \dfrac{dv}{dx} + v &= v - 1 \\
x \dfrac{dv}{dx} &= - 1 \\
dv &= - \dfrac{dx}{x} \\
v &= -\ln x + c \\
\dfrac{y}{x} &= -\ln{|x|} + c \\
y &= -x \ln {|x|} + cx
\end{align*}

The book's answer is:
$$ y = x \ln{|\frac{k}{x}|} $$
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$y = -x \ln{|x|}+cx$

$=x\ln{|\frac{1}{x}|}+cx$

$=x(\ln{|\frac{1}{x}|+\ln{k}})$, put $c = \ln{k}$

$y=x(\ln{|\frac{k}{x}|})$, you did everything right

Answer (score 5):

You didn't do anything wrong. Your book just took the constant $c$ to be $\ln |k|$.